# Got parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";" even though there is already a semi-colon

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to React, and am trying to create a portfolio project. While I was doing this, I got an error that I need to add a semi-colon on line 3 even though I already added a semi-colon to this line. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class Footer extends Component {
  render: function(); {
  return (

  <footer>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="twelve columns">
        <ul className="social-links">
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-facebook" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-twitter" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-google-plus" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-linkedin" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-instagram" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-dribbble" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-skype" /></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul className="copyright">
          <li>© Copyright 2014 CeeVee</li>
          <li>Design by <a title="Styleshout" href="http://www.styleshout.com/">Styleshout</a></li>   
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="go-top"><a className="smoothscroll" title="Back to Top" href="#home"><i className="icon-up-open" /></a></div>
    </div>
  </footer> {/* Footer End*/}
);
}
};
  </React.Fragment>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Why is there an unrelated `</React.Fragment>` and followed by unbalanced closing parentheses and curly braces?

Comment: @emile-bergeron I copy-pasted HTML code into a JSX convertor, and this is the code I got back.

Comment: JSX isn't really far from HTML in term of learning curve, you should take the time to read the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html), which is really well written and complete. Using some converter is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is here,

```
render: function(); {   //This `;` is the issue which is end of line and syntax error
```

it should be

```
render: function() {
```

Comment: I tried removing the semicolon, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: You have to remove everything from `</React.Fragment>` to the last. It is not required.

Answer (score 0):

As per react perspective render() is a life cycle hook of the component. And it renders content on the browser. The basic sample code for the component will be like...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Footer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <footer>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="twelve columns">
        <ul className="social-links">
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-facebook" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-twitter" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-google-plus" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-linkedin" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-instagram" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-dribbble" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-skype" /></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul className="copyright">
          <li>© Copyright 2014 CeeVee</li>
          <li>Design by <a title="Styleshout" href="http://www.styleshout.com/">Styleshout</a></li>   
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="go-top"><a className="smoothscroll" title="Back to Top" href="#home"><i className="icon-up-open" /></a></div>
    </div>
  </footer>
        );
    }
}
```

This will be run without errors.